# Angular material animations not working after using custom theme

Tags: angular, animation, angular-material

I'm using angular material version 7  and angular version 7
After i change to custom theme
It seems like all work accept the animations
The mat-progress-bar stopped move like it should

this is my progress-bar

```
<mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>
```

and here is the custom theme

```
$my-primary: (
  50: #34495e,
  100: #34495e,
  200: #34495e,
  300: #34495e,
  400: #34495e,
  500: #34495e,
  600: #34495e,
  700: #34495e,
  800: #34495e,
  900: #34495e,
  A100: #34495e,
  A200: #34495e,
  A400: #34495e,
  A700: #34495e,
  contrast: (
    50: white,
    100: white,
    200: white,
    300: white,
    400: white,
    500: white,
    600: white,
    700: white,
    800: white,
    900: white,
    A100: white,
    A200: white,
    A400: white,
    A700: white
  )
);

$my-secondary: (
 // like above
);
// custom theme
@include mat-core();
$app-primary: mat-palette($my-primary);
$app-accent: mat-palette($my-secondary);
$app-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);
$app-theme: mat-light-theme($app-primary, $app-accent, $app-warn);
@include angular-material-theme($app-theme);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste in the imports of your module? Ensure that BrowserAnimationsModule is imported.

Also check that NoopAnimationsModule is not imported.

Comment: I'm importing the BrowserAnimationsModule. if I change the theme to the original everything work fine

Comment: I am expecting this is a cli app?
Have you imported this under styles key?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. i changed the primary color 50 100 200 300 400 to lighter color